# How do I calculate the definite integral $\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx$ using complex variables?

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

I have tried solving the integral $\oint_{C}\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}dz$ using the upper semi-circle contour; I am getting the poles $z=\pm i$.

Only $z=i$ exists within the contour and I have evaluated the residue at $z=i$ as follows:
$Res(z=i)=\lim_{z\to i} (z-i)\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}i}$

Using residue theorem, I am ending up with $\oint_{C}\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}dz = \sqrt{2}\pi$.

I am confused as to how to proceed from this point.

Comment: You have already [posted this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3879587/446262).

Comment: By dividing the contour into the actual semicircle and the straight line between -1 and 1, are you able to find a relation between the integral you have solved and the one you are interested in?

Comment: I am ending up with $\int_{-R}^{+R}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx + \int_{C_{R}}\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}dz = \sqrt{2}\pi$; Now I'll have to show that $\lim_{R\to 1} \int_{C_{R}}\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}dz = \pi$, which is where I'm confused.

Comment: @TejaTeppala Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be given by

$$I=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx$$

Next, let $C$ be the classical dog bone contour around $[-1,1]$ in the complex plane.  It is straightforward to show that

$$\oint_C \frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}\,dz=-2I$$

since $C$ is traversed in the counter-clockwise direction.

---

In the following analysis, we cut the plane with branch cuts along the real axis from the branch points at $\pm 1$ to $-\infty$.  These two branch cut coalesce as a branch cut from $-1$ to $1$.  We ensure that the chosen branches are taken such that on the real axis above the branch cut $[-1,1]$, we have $\sqrt{1-x^2}\ge 0$.

---

Using the Residue Theorem, we have for $R>1$

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}\,dz&=\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}\,dz-2\pi i\,\text{Res}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}, z=\pm 1\right)\\\\
&=\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}\,dz-2\pi i \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2i}+\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{-2i}\right)\tag1
\end{align}$$

Since $R$ is arbitrary, we can let $R\to \infty$.  Proceeding accordingly we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{R\to \infty}\oint_{|z|=R }\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}\,dz&=\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sqrt{1-R^2e^{i2\phi}}}{1+R^2e^{i2\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=2\pi\tag2 
\end{align}$$

---

**NOTE:**

In arriving at $(2)$, we wrote $\sqrt{1-R^2e^{i2\phi}}=-i\sqrt{R^2e^{i2\phi}-1}$,  which is consistent with the chosen branch.

---

Finally, using $(2)$ in $(1)$ we find that

$$\oint_C \frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1+z^2}\,dz =2\pi(1-\sqrt {2}) \tag3$$

whereupon dividing $(3)$ by $-2$ yields the coveted result

$$I=2\pi (\sqrt 2-1)$$

And we are done!

Comment: @TejaTeppala Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Comment: Would the down voter care to comment?  Or was this a frivalous and indiscriminate behavior?